# Regex. How to match just 2 digit numbers in a string

Tags: regex

I want to get the 2 digit number and no number from more digit numbers.
For example in string or word
Hi3020want07see
I just want the number 07, no digits from the 4 digit number (3020). Is there a pantern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
(?<!\d)\d\d(?!\d)
```

This is matching 2 digits not preceded or followed by other digits.